# Turn my joomla component into a wordpress plugin

Tags: component, development, wordpress

I develope a really big eCommerce component for Joomla 3.4.

I have noted that other developers like jomres or Akeeba backup have, from some tine now, a version of their components for Wordpress.

I guess, that like me, they use Joomla API and MVC extensively and I don´t think they have reprogramed again fo WP.

So my question is:

How can I turn my joomla component into a WP plugin without refactoring?
Is that posible?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Akeeba uses FOF (Framework on Framwork), it doesn't directly use Joomla. So there is a middle layer and I guess he just can swap out that layer to another one and have it work on Wordpress and standalone. But it's just guessing :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately no, this is not possible. Joomla and Wordpress are completely different CMS's with different code structures.

Joomla is build using MVC(Model, View, Controller) where as Wordpress, well I can't even think of a word to describe the architecture. **"Odd"** would be the first thing that springs to mind.

So a complete re-write would be required.

Comment: jeje I coud not describe it better. I however has the suspiction that there is a way to use joomla framework, not the whole cms, inside WP

Comment: Yes, this is also possible, but would be extremely overkill just for 1 extension. Each framework package normally relies on another, therefore you will end up having to use the entire framework.